# Where to install sync and reporting scripts?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a linux server and a whole bunch of scripts that are used to run reports off of some databases and also sync data among various databases.  All these scripts are to be run in cron.  Should I install them to `/home/scripts/` and run them in scripts cron?  Or should I install them to `/usr/share/scripts/` (or should they be somewhere else) and run them in root's cron?  I kind of like the idea of having all the scripts in one directory (as they have many subdirectories).  They'll also be version controlled.  Oh, and the server is dedicated to just these scripts.

Answer (score 2):

- Put it in anywhere you want
- Run them in the user's cron who has enough permission to access and
  execute.